# how to update the child module parent version

Tags: maven, parent-child, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

```
HI My project structure is like this

    parentPrj
    pom.xml
    childModule1
         pom.xml
    ChildModule2
        pom.xml
    ChildModule2
        pom.xml

    I dont want to build all the child builds so I am building each module based on the profile (something like below)
```

// here is the some sample code

```
   <profiles>
                     <profile>
                        <id>child1</id>
                        <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                        </activation>
                        <modules>
                            <module>childModule1</module>
                        </modules>
                    </profile>
                    <profile>
                        <id>child2</id>
                        <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                        </activation>
                        <modules>
                            <module>childModule2</module>
                        </modules>
                    </profile>
                    <profile>
                        <id>child3</id>
                        <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                        </activation>
                        <modules>
                            <module>childModule3</module>
                        </modules>
                    </profile>
            </profiles>
```

// end of the sample code
        My goal is when I run child1 profile I wanted to build childModule1 project and update the parent version of the pom in all three child modules .. Can you help me how to do that? I have tried many options like 
        release:update-versions -DautoVersionSubmodules=true ,mvn versions:set etc..

Comment: "I dont want to build all the child builds so I am building each module based on the profile". I admit I stopped reading here. If you don't want to build the child, then a multi-module project isn't what you want. You want separate distinct projects.

Comment: thanks Tunaki..but I wanted to maintain the same version across all the modules irrespective of the build

Comment: So it is contradictory then: either all projects are part of the same multi-module project, have the same release cycle and share the same version, OR they do not and you should have multiple distinct projects. Make your life easy and use Maven the way it's supposed to be used :).

Comment: What you need is a way to make a partial build? Describe why you'd want child1 and not child2.